# Can I create additional axes/dimensions in Premake?

Tags: premake

Premake 5 gives you two functions to separate independent configuration variables in your projects: `configurations` and `platforms`. So for example, you might have:

```
configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
platform { "Windows", "Linux" }
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Configurations-and-Platforms) refers to these as axes, which is a good way to describe them, since you can have independent settings for each axis:

> Really, platforms are just another set of build configuration names, providing another axis on which to configure your project.

But what if I want another axis? For example, the data types used for particular calculations:

```
calctypes { "Long", "Default", "Short" }
```

Can I create this new axis, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [tags](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/789) (a new feature due to be released in the next alpha build) might be what you're looking for. Here is an example from the pull request where they were implemented:

```
workspace 'foobar'
    configurations { 'release-std', 'debug-std', 'release-blz', 'debug-blz' }

   filter { 'configuration:*-std' }
        tags { 'use-std' }
   filter { 'configuration:*-blz' }
        tags { 'use-blz' }

   project 'test'
        filter { 'tags:use-blz' }
            includedependencies { 'blz' }
            defines { 'USE_BLZ' }

        filter { 'tags:use-std' }
            defines { 'USE_STD' }
```

**Update:** If you would like to see how to add custom fields (e.g. `defines`, `configurations`, etc.), have a look at the `api.register()` calls in [_premake_init.lua](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/master/src/_premake_init.lua). To see how to enable filtering on one of these fields, [have a look at this pull request](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/882).

While adding new fields is trivial and can be done anywhere, we need to do some work before it will be as simple to enable those fields for filtering.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I think it depends on how many different axes I have. If it's just data type, this will work. If there's more, I think I might end up duplicating a lot of "multiplication" code. What about extensions (or modules, I think they're called)? Could a module achieve this?

Comment: I would need a more concrete example to be able to answer that fully.

Comment: That's fair enough. This will get me going, and if I have more specific questions about extending Premake I'll ask here or on the dev list.

Comment: Updated answer with more information on how you might implement new fields (i.e. with a module).